# StatusListener and TwitterStream class are not available in jar

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to access twitter API using twitter4j.I am trying it through [Streaming API](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html)(point 9).But **StatusListener** and **TwitterStream** are not present.I checkecd jar as well,they are not present there also.
I added

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.5</version>
   </dependency>
```

in pom.xml to add jars.TwitterStream  seems to present in [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html) since 2.2.0.I am using **2.2.5** which is latest stable build.But still these classes are not present in jar.
     Please tell me if anybody else had same problem or has the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following dependecies needs to be added in pom for twitter4j-stream.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
<artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0</version>
```

Comment: Where can I find pom.xml to add the above dependecies?